Combining SELECT * columns with GROUP BY query
I need to combine the results of the following two queries in one query.
Query #1:
SELECT 
    sets.set_num, sets.name AS set_name, sets.year, sets.theme_id, 
    sets.num_parts, themes.name AS theme_name 
FROM 
    sets
INNER JOIN 
    themes ON sets.theme_id = themes.id 
WHERE 
    (sets.year IS NULL OR sets.year LIKE '%' || :set_year || '%') 
    AND (sets.name IS NULL OR sets.name LIKE '%' || :set_name || '%') 
    AND (themes.name IS NULL OR themes.name LIKE '%' || :theme_name || '%') 
ORDER BY 
    set_num 
LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset

Query #2:
SELECT 
    COUNT(a.set_num) AS count, a.year AS key 
FROM 
    (SELECT sets.set_num, sets.year 
     FROM sets 
     INNER JOIN themes ON sets.theme_id = themes.id 
     WHERE (sets.year IS NULL OR sets.year LIKE '%' || :set_year || '%') 
       AND (sets.name IS NULL OR sets.name LIKE '%' || :set_name || '%') 
       AND (themes.name IS NULL OR themes.name LIKE '%' || :theme_name || '%') 
     LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset) AS a 
GROUP BY 
    a.year

Is it possible to make these two queries into one since they both have the same joins and conditions?
I want to end up with the same result but with executing one query:
{
    "sets": [
        {
            "num": "21162-1",
            "name": "The Taiga Adventure",
            "year": 2020,
            "themeId": 577,
            "themeName": "Minecraft",
            "numParts": 74
        }
    ],
    "setCountByYear": [
        {
            "key": "2020",
            "count": 1
        }
    ]
}

Schema of the sets table:
CREATE TABLE sets 
(
    set_num varchar(16) PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(128),
    year smallint,
    theme_id smallint,
    num_parts int,
    FOREIGN KEY(theme_id) REFERENCES themes(id)
);

Schema of the themes table:
CREATE TABLE themes 
(
    id smallint PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(64),
    parent_id smallint
);

Sample data for sets table:



set_num
name
year
theme_id
num_parts




001-1
Gears
1965
1
43


0011-2
Town Mini-Figures
1978
84
12


0011-3
Castle 2 for 1 Bonus Offer
1987
199
0


0012-1
Space Mini-Figures
1979
143
12


0013-1
Space Mini-Figures
1979
143
12



Sample data for themes:



id
name
parent_id




1
Technic



2
Arctic Technic
1


3
Competition
1


4
Expert Builder
1


5
Model
1




Seems like a job for a window function. add COUNT(sets.set_num) OVER (PARTITION BY sets.year ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as count to your first query.

What is the expected output ?

@AmiraBedhiafi the expected output after using a RowMapper is mentioned in the question in the json representation.

@AmiraBedhiafi after adding the query you mentioned, I did not get the expected result set

@AmiraBedhiafi the issue is that I need two different data structures in one query, that is the main idea.

If you just wanted an extra column on your data, then you could use a window function:
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY s.year)

But what you are asking for is really two separate resultsets. The best you can do is use a CTE and combine them using JSON.
It's unclear why you expect those columns to be null, or why you would want to use LIKE on numeric columns.
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
      s.set_num,
      s.name AS set_name,
      s.year,
      s.theme_id,
      s.num_parts,
      t.name AS theme_name
    FROM
        sets s
    INNER JOIN 
        themes t ON s.theme_id = t.id 
    WHERE
        s.year = :set_year
        AND s.name LIKE '%' || :set_name || '%'
        AND t.name LIKE '%' || :theme_name || '%'
    ORDER BY
        set_num 
    LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset
)
SELECT
  json_object(
    'sets', (
        SELECT json_group_array(json_object(
          'set_num', set_num,
          'set_name', set_name,
          'year', year,
          'theme_id', theme_id, 
          'num_parts', num_parts,
          'theme_name', theme_name 
        ))
        FROM cte
    ),
    'setCountByYear', (
        SELECT json_group_array(json(eachYear))
        FROM (
            SELECT
              json_object(
                'key', year,
                'count', COUNT(*)
              ) AS eachYear
            FROM cte
            GROUP BY
                year
        ) j1
    )
  ) AS json;

db<>fiddle

got an error:
sqlite SQLITE_ERROR: sqlite3 result code 1: misuse of aggregate function COUNT()

also modified the query to use HAVING instead of WHERE and got another error:
SQLITE_ERROR: sqlite3 result code 1: HAVING clause on a non-aggregate query

Why did you change that? Did you leave in the GROUP BY year? Can you construct a https://dbfiddle.uk showing the tables and the code?

Okay, I will set up one.

https://dbfiddle.uk/pcPNKmfl

OK those issues are fixed. By the way your fiddle was incorrect: tables were created and inserted in the wrong order, and the data didn't match the foreign key relationship.

actually when i run it on my end, it gives me an error:
"code": "SQLITE_ERROR" and a message pops up with the error: "run failed"

Are you running a version of SQlite that supports the JSON functions? https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html Because it works in the fiddle I posted. Note the change from jsonb to json because jsonb is only supported from version 3.45.0

Yes, I saw it now and looks like its works fine, but is there a way to avoid using the json representation and get the raw data only? I just wanna map the data that comes from the query using Spring RowMapper, can it still be a single query without json?

I just see that mapping data to json and converting it to objects will have more cost than just using the row data directly and converting it to objects without the json conversion step.

For that you would have to just run two separate queries. If you have a different question than what you originally asked then you should post a new question

This is what I wanted to know, it is two queries to solve this problem in the end, it can be combined only in case of returning json as the query result format. Okay, thank you so much Charlieface. Your effort is much appreciated.
